# qsort on equal sized list of char arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

I have a list of character arrays **malloc**ed as follows.

```
list= (char**)malloc(LIST_SIZE* sizeof(*list));
for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    list[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 33);//33 is the size of each element in the list
```

The size of the list can grow as big as **25,000(LIST_SIZE)** or sometimes may be just 10 elements or less.

I have the **compare()** function which is giving errors.

```
    int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const char **fpa = (const char**)a;
    const char **fpb = (const char**)b;
    return strcmp(*fpa, *fpb);
    //return *(char *)a - *(char*)b;//This one also does not work
}
```

**qsort()** is invoked like this. I suspect it fails because of the way it is invoked but I could not understand why.

```
qsort(list, current_list_element_count, 33, compare);
```

Comment: `qsort(list, current_list_element_count, sizeof *list, &compare);`

Comment: @Stargateur you mean why did I use a magic number? or why the size 33?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see `list[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 33);` but as dbush say this is not the size that expect `qsort()`

Comment: OT: This `const char **fpa = (const char**)a;` ought to be `char * const *fpa = a;`.

Comment: OT^2: No need to cast `malloc()`. At least *if* you really do C and not C++.

Comment: @alk Accepted! I was testing it on MSVC.

Comment: OT^3: In C++ this `const char **fpa = (const char**)a;` ought to be `char * const *fpa = (char * const *) a;`. Your cast hammers  the constness to wrong level.

Comment: 33 bytes is a really strange size! Any explicit `#pragma`tic  `pack`ing involved?

Comment: @alk The list contains md5 value of file fingerprints **32 bytes for md5 and a byte for null terminator**

Comment: Ah well, makes sense. I was expecting a `struct` for, to be honest, unknown reasons ... please excuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in the wrong value for the element size to `qsort`.

Even though you allocate 33 bytes for each array, you don't actually have an array of arrays.  What you have is an array of *pointers*, each of which points to an array.

Since each member of the array is a `char *`, you want to pass the size of that:

```
qsort(list, current_list_element_count, sizeof(char *), compare);
```

Or more generally:

```
qsort(list, current_list_element_count, sizeof(*list), compare);
```

This way, what you pass for the size doesn't depend on the type.

Comment: Note: even if this answer use the word `array` to be easy to read, they are not array but pointer to a contigus number of the same type.

Comment: @Stargateur How would the **array** equivalent be? I mean its declaration and allocation.

Comment: @John_D `int list1[10]` and `int list2[25000][33]` are both _arrays_. `int *list3[25000]` is an array (of pointers).  Given "grow as big as 25,000", perhasp use `list3` and `strdup()`?